# How to write a string containing ascii codes into the Registry?

Tags: inno-setup

I need to write the following value into the Registry during setup:

```
[Registry]
Root: HKCU; Subkey: "Software\Apt\TCM\Tables\Standard"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "Campaign planner"; ValueData: "Sent letter #1¦TOGGLE:TICK2¦1500\01Follow-up call¦TOGGLE:TICK2¦1500\01¦SPACE¦45\01Sent letter #2¦TOGGLE:TICK2¦1500\01Follow-up call¦TOGGLE:TICK2¦1500\01¦SPACE¦45\01Notes¦¦4000"
```

but where it says "\01" I need to write ASCII character 01, so it would be entered like this:

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: Where are you getting the value? Is it hard-coded somewhere?

Comment: `StringChangeEx` your `\01` with `#1`.

Comment: So if I write "Hello#1World" as ValueData I'll get "Hello[]World" in the Registry where [] is ascii character 1?

Comment: No, that won't work. It would work if you'd pass such string into the `StringChangeEx` function in `[Code]`, or maybe also with preprocessor's `StringChange`. But to get specific help, respond to @Ken's comment (or update your question), please. P.S. ASCII char 1 is not printable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way might be replacing all the occurences of the `\01` sequence by the [`StringChange`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=stringchange) function at compilation time. Though I couldn't find a way how to escape the SOH (ASCII char 1) without turning off the Pascal style string literals, this will do the job:

```
#pragma parseroption -p-

[Registry]
...; ValueData: "{#StringChange('Lorem ipsum\01dolor sit amet', '\01', '\x01')}"
```

However, the code above looks to me overcomplicated. If you don't mind that all the backslash escaped chars will evaluate to their corresponding chars, you may define a variable that will escape them:

```
#pragma parseroption -p-
#define MyValue "Lorem ipsum\01dolor sit amet"

[Registry]
...; ValueData: "{#MyValue}"
```

But note that it applies to all backslash escaped chars, like `\02`, `\03` and all their respective notations, which might not always fit to your constant value.

Still, as the most reliable way I'm finding to use the code section with its [`StringChangeEx`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_stringchangeex) function.

Comment: That works perfectly. It doesn't matter that the lines appear in red in the editor?

Comment: That is correct. It is the syntax highlighting for preprocessor expressions.